# How to iterate over a list and get values one by one either in descending or ascending order continously?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a list that has button names.First of all, these buttons are for touchscreen devices and a touch_move event causes the button to have a different name based on the list. So i am not displaying all buttons at once. I want to be able to display a continuous list i.e button 1 - 10 that repeats itself as long as there is an event.

```
def get_nextname(self, *args):
    #self.get_button_names is a list of names
    num = len(self.get_button_names)
    count = 0
    while (count <= num):
        self.c1name.text = self.get_button_names[count]
        count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle over button objects:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle

>>> buttons = range(1, 11)
>>> buttons_cycle = cycle(buttons)

>>> for _ in xrange(20):
...     print buttons_cycle.next()

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

or cycle over button list's indices:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle

>>> buttons = range(1, 11)
>>> idx_cycle = cycle(xrange(len(buttons)))

>>> for _ in xrange(20):
...     print buttons[idx_cycle.next()]
```

Whichever suits you best. Personally, I'd stick to the first version.

Keep in mind that `itertools.cycle` stores the list it is cycling over internally.

Comment: Great way of doing this. I think my problem lies more in the fact that i need to keep track of my events because i am getting one button name with each call even though the button name list is healthy.

Comment: @ChemSolver, store the `cycle` object somewhere and use it in your event handlers. This way you can keep cycling through it.